# Join multiple tables without duplicate row

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select 3 tables with the code number is 777

```
Table 1 
Employee code    Company Name
001                  a
002                  b


Table 2
Employee code    Voucher NO      Date         Amount
001               123            12-4-14      100
001               456            2-5-14       500
002               789            3 -7 14      300

Table 3
Voucher No     Tax amt     code
123             50         777
789             100        888
```

The output should be

```
Company Name    Employee code  Voucher No    Date         Amount    Tax amt     code
a                 001             123           12-4-14      100       50         777
a                 001             456           2-5-14       500       null       null
```

but there are duplicate row when apply the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 table1.COMPANY_NAME,
 table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
 table2.VOUCHER_NO,
 table2.DATE,
 table2.AMOUNT,
 table3.TAX_AMT, 
 table3.CODE
 FROM table2
 INNER JOIN table1 ON (table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE = table1.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table2.VOUCHER_NO = table3.VOUCHER_NO ) 
WHERE table3.CODE = '777'
```

The output from the above query

```
Company Name   Employee code   Voucher No    Date     Amount    Tax amt     code
a                 001           123        12-4-14      100       50         777
a                 001           456        2-5-14       500     **50       777**
```

I got try to use DISTINCT but since no work well. Please kindly help what problem with my query.

Comment: How can the second row in your expected output be expected when you filter out everything that does not have code=777 (null is not 777) / why would you want to drop seemingly random data from random columns?

Comment: Why should the tax amount and code for voucher 456 be `null`? Can you explain the logic you're trying to produce?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the background? For example, in your expected output, why should there be two rows anyway, if you ask for code 777? The second row in your output does not even have this code?

Comment: in addition to mureinik's question, if it's not important, you can ignore the values in the `Tax amt` and `code` column of row > 1 at data / business layer of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    table1.COMPANY_NAME,
    table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
    table2.VOUCHER_NO,
    table2.DATE,
    table2.AMOUNT,
    table3.TAX_AMT, 
    table3.CODE
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON (table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE = table1.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table2.VOUCHER_NO = table3.VOUCHER_NO ) 
HAVING
    (table3.CODE = '777' OR table3.CODE IS NULL)
```

Leave me a comment if you need something else, or if you have a specific issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.it show error message after apply the coding com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=CODE, DRIVER=3.64.114

Comment: :$ Cannot really know from where it comes from, anyway if you need to get only row with code = '777' or row where there is no code linked, you should use HAVING CLAUSE. I can help you more if give me a filled SQLFIDDLE like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/19ba8/1

Comment: I just need the row with code = '777' without duplicate the data in 3rd table

Comment: Please give me a full sample in sqlfiddle, so I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example output wasn't produced by your SQL command since you use `WHERE` statement to filter.

If you need to output only `777` code you should use LEFT JOIN with condition instead of WHERE

```
 ..... 
 FROM table2
 INNER JOIN table1 ON (table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE = table1.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
 LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table2.VOUCHER_NO = table3.VOUCHER_NO ) 
                     AND (table3.CODE = '777')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The table is display the output only 777, but the main problem it also show duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Your second row in your output maybe because it has the same `EMPLOYEE_CODE` in table2, so I think this may the query that you want:

```
SELECT
 table1.COMPANY_NAME,
 table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
 table2.VOUCHER_NO,
 table2.DATE,
 table2.AMOUNT,
 table3.TAX_AMT, 
 table3.CODE
 FROM table2
 INNER JOIN table1 ON (table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE = table1.EMPLOYEE_CODE)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table2.VOUCHER_NO = table3.VOUCHER_NO ) 
WHERE table1.EMPLOYEE_CODE IN
(SELECT table2.EMPLOYEE_CODE 
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table3 ON (table2.VOUCHER_NO = table3.VOUCHER_NO)
WHERE table3.code = '777')
```

Comment: thanks but all the row are duplicate twice after using the coding